# How can i remove all SetOptions?

Tags: input-alias

I downloaded some package.
They give new Aliases such as "braket" notation.
But i hope to reset everything.
they have so many options, it is not easy to remove individually.
I mean that i want initialized mathematica version (before run the package)

Comment: The easiest is simply to start a new kernel. If you know the context you may also say Clean["YourContext`*"] this cleans all the functions and variables in context: "YourContext"

Comment: Thank you for your answering. But problem is that when i start on new kernel after turn off my computer, the Aliases still remain.

Comment: You do not need to turn your computer off to start a new kernel, simply choose "Quit Kernel" in the "Evaluation" menu. Then, if the aliases are still there with a new kernel, they must be defined in the initialization file "init.m". Search this file and see if something defined aliases there.